# why doesn't this code return all rows?

Tags: php, database, odbc

I have an access database, and one of the tables is called `Products`, which contains 9 rows.
I want to `echo` all of the rows, but when I use this code, it will `echo` only 4 rows.
Where is my fault ?

```
$conn = odbc_connect('MoeinODBCTest1', '', '');
$sql = "select * from Products";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

while(odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
   $arr = odbc_fetch_array($rs);
   print_r($arr);
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: use echo odbc_num_rows($rs); and tell what is the result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both odbc_fetch_array and odbc_fetch_row are pulling rows out of the results.

Try instead:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('MoeinODBCTest1', '', '');
$sql = "select * from Products";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

while($arr = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    print_r($arr);
   echo '
';
}
```

Comment: I wonder why ODBC won't bring all results instead of making me spend 4 hours trying to figure out why `odbc_fetch_array` was bringing only one result at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching rows both when calling `odbc_fetch_row` and `odbc_fetch_array`, so every second row gets discarded.

Since `odbc_fetch_array` returns `FALSE` when there are no more rows, you can use it to fetch the next row and check if there are any more rows, at the same time:

```
while ($arr = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    print_r($arr);
    echo "\n";
}
```