# PHP odbc_exec not returning all rows

Tags: php, sql, odbc

This simple query

```
SELECT 
    DBA.Goods.ID,  /* PK in the Goods table */
    DBA.Goods.Name,
    DBA.GoodsGroup.Name as GdGrp,
    DBA.InvoiceItem.Qty,
    DBA.InvoiceItem.ID,   /* PK in the InvoiceItem table */
    DBA.InvoiceItem.PrintName,
    DBA.InvoiceItem.Price,
    DBA.InvoiceItem.InvoiceID, /* PK in the Invoice table, a parent table of a sort */
    DBA.InvoiceItem.InvoiceItemOrder,
    DBA.InvoiceItem.ProcPrice,
FROM (
    DBA.Goods INNER JOIN DBA.InvoiceItem
        ON DBA.Goods.GoodsSk = DBA.InvoiceItem.GoodsSK
)
INNER JOIN DBA.GoodsGroup
    ON DBA.Goods.GroupID = DBA.GoodsGroup.ID
WHERE DBA.InvoiceItem.InvoiceID = $invoiceID /* ID of a specific invoice, used here to get to its contents, i.e. specific items within that invoice */
```

when run in DBExplorer (a DB tool for executing raw SQL queries), returns 5 rows (contents of an invoice). Everything is setup in such a way that an invoice may contain multiple goods of the same ID (but with different prices and procurement prices, printing names - e.g. bucket-white, bucket-blue, bucket-red, etc). Each of the items gets a unique ID within the `Items` table. The aforementioned 5 rows are the expected result (i.e. the goods in the list are the actual goods sold).

However, when the query is sent to the database via:

```
$result = odbc_exec($conn,$query);
```

`odbc_num_rows($results)` is not 5, as expected and seen in DBExplorer, but 3 - the (percieved) duplicates are not returned (of all the buckets in the previous example, only one is returned).

Furthermore, while looping through the results with

```
while($rowItems = odbc_fetch_object($result) {
    ...
}
```

there are only 3 iterations, instead of the expected 5.

Thinking that the column order might be causing problems (silly, I know), I moved the `DBA.InvoiceItem.ID` to the top, making it the first column in the result set. However, that did nothing.

Why is this happening, and how can I make it return the full result set?

**Note**

I am aware that there are similar questions on SO:

[php odbc_exec not returning all results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030330/php-odbc-exec-not-returning-all-results)

[why doesn't this code return all rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367414/why-doesnt-this-code-return-all-rows)

[Not getting all rows from a query with odbc_exec in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303060/not-getting-all-rows-from-a-query-with-odbc-exec-in-php)

but none of them actually address the issue presented here - how to get ALL of the rows as seen in the DB tool, instead of a reduced result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was with the query. As soon as I'd changed it by changing the joining order, everything worked as expected. The key was to make `DBA.InvoiceItem` the main table, and join everything with it. I still have no (clear) idea why this worked.